# Voltage drop when reading an NFC tag

Tags: voltage

I have developed a hardware for a project. It has several features, including an RFID reader.(PN7150)

I've been working for the last few weeks on that part of the project and I've been able to read the tag information satisfactorily.

When I came back with other parts of the project, I noticed that a TFT screen that the hardware has, was restarting when presenting the tag. (other devices have no problems)

So using an oscilloscope I have determined that the reason is a voltage drop at the time of presenting the tag to the RFID antenna.

The yellow arrows indicate small voltage drops that occur when the IC tries to detect a present tag, while the green arrow represents a large voltage drop when the tag is present on the antenna.

[image]

This voltage drop is the cause of the reset of the TFT screen. (Part of the chip (PN7150) works with 5V and the TFT too)

Now I assumed that may be a voltage source current supply problem. **I have measured the current of all the hardware when the Tag is presented and it comes to approximately 450mA.**

The sources that I'm using are of the switching type, initially I was using one that supplies up to 1 amp, I changed to another that supplies 2 A and the problem is the same.

I also assumed that it might be a resonance problem between the RFID antenna and the switching source, so I changed to a linear one with a transformer, rectifier and an LDO regulator, but the problem continues.

I don't know what else it could be, the current consumption does not exceed the maximum allowed by the source to assume that this is the cause. It is also not a short duration transient to affirm that for this reason the source cannot compensate for the sudden increase in current (in the graph it can be measured that said drop is approximately 700 ms.

I attach an image of the source integrated in the PCB.

[image]

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Update.

I have made a bridge with a cable to avoid the rectifier diode, the image that shows the voltage drop is with the cable that short-circuits the diode.

Comment: You have a 1.2v max drop out voltage at 500mA on your regulator, but your nominal voltage is only about 4.6-4.7, with much lower dips. That is not much margin. I would consider getting rid of that diode on the input and/or switching to an LDO with a < 600-1000 mV drop out.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I forgot to mention that. I have made a bridge in the rectifier diode, the image with the voltage drop is with said bridge. Thks for writing

Comment: You still don't have much margin. Consider an actual LDO instead of an 1117, which was low-dropout when it first came out but wouldn't be considered an LDO by today's standards.

Comment: The problem is not in the output of the LM1117, everything that is connected to the output of the LM1117 works correctly, it is in the 5 V that come from an external source. I'm suspecting that the fuse is causing the problem. I'm going to make the measurements of the 5V before the fuse.

Comment: Agree that the voltage sag on 5v isn't good. Do you have a picture of the setup? How much current is being drawn when it dips? I would expect those caps to help a lot.

Comment: It's the fuse. I've shorted it and the voltage drops are very small. I will answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered that the problem is the fuse. I have short-circuited it, the TFT doesn't reset and the voltage drops are small:

[image]

The fuse is soldered to the PCB, to avoid false contact resistance, even so it is the cause of the problem. According to the manufacturer, it has a cold resistance of 0.33 ohms.

I would have to find another solution to replace the fuse with something that does not cause the problem.

**Update 1**

After determining that the cause of the problem is the fuse, I'm assuming the reason for this phenomenon.

The fuse has a fault current of 500 mA, and the current that is consumed (of all the hardware) when the NFC tag is read reaches about 450 mA, so, I think, when the current reaches the limit of the fuse , it begins to increase its resistance to produce enough heat to melt, but since it is not yet the maximum failure, it only increased the resistance and at the same time produces the voltage drop.

I should try a higher rated fuse, that way I could test my theory. Since the fault current is greater than 500 mA, the 450 mA from the hardware would not cause the fuse resistance to increase.

At **@RemyHx**'s request, I upload the schematic of the NFC chip.

[image]

**Update 2**

I have done the test with a 1A fuse and everything works without problems. It was definitely a mistake to use a fuse whose fault current was close to the maximum that the hardware draws.

Maybe you should test with fuses in ranges between 600mA to 700mA

Comment: But is it the fuse then, or the small margin you already have? Can you share the rfid schematic?

Comment: OK, I will update the answer with the schematic and my theory as to why the problem occurs.

Comment: Ah it's more clear to me now. Guess you're right about the fuse!